# Positioning a section next to figure

Tags: css, html

i have a sections in an aritcle. And a figures in the same article. I have 3 sections and 3 figures. What i want is to align the section and figure side by side alternatively. For example,

```
   #ARICLE#
       #SECTION#  #FIGURE #
       #FIGURE #  #SECTION#
   #END
```

So far i tried floating the figure... However the figure appears to be on top of the section. I want both of them to be seperated side by side. Heres the html

```
    <article>
        <section id="about">
            <header>About me</header>
            <p>
               A text                
            </p>
        </section>
        <figure>
            <img src="css/images/body2.jpg" height="200" width="300" />
            <figcaption>An image</figcaption>
        </figure>
   </article>
```

My section have a different background, my figure will contain a different a image. My body have a different background as well. heres the css

```
section {
      background-image: url("images/paper.png");
      padding-right: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;  
}

figure {
      margin-right: 15px;
      float: left;
}
```

When i try to float the image, it appears to be on top of the section background. I want them separated. How do i achieve this? Thank you.
EDIT**
PLEASE avoid divs. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead** of using `float` Use `display:inline-block;` & `width:40%` for both section & figure to display it side by side.

```css
section {
      background-image: url("images/paper.png");
   }

  section,figure {
      display:inline-block;  
      width:40%;
    padding-right: 20px;
      padding-left: 20px;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

```html
<article>
        <section id="about">
            <header>About me</header>
            <p>
               A text                
            </p>
        </section>
        <figure>
            <img src="css/images/body2.jpg" height="200" width="300" />
            <figcaption>An image</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <img src="css/images/body2.jpg" height="200" width="300" />
            <figcaption>An image</figcaption>
        </figure>
  <section id="about">
            <header>About me</header>
            <p>
               A text                
            </p>
        </section>

  <section id="about">
            <header>About me</header>
            <p>
               A text                
            </p>
        </section>
        <figure>
            <img src="css/images/body2.jpg" height="200" width="300" />
            <figcaption>An image</figcaption>
        </figure>
   </article>
```

Comment: Great! However I have 3 sections and 3 figures all in 1 article. If I do that everything will be in 1 line however, I need to separate each pair of section and article from top to bottom as well. If inline I can't do padding at the top or below. Is there a way to only apply that for only for  same class names?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?